# How to set Visual Studio's Open MP Support (Yes /openmp) in the CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, openmp

How can I enable Open MP support using the CMakeLists.txt file for a Visual Studio 2019 C++ project?
[image: Yes (/openmp)]